# Create multiple menu dropdowns based upon 1st rollover, 2nd rollover, 3rd rollover etc

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-data-validation

Example:

User selects a cell for dropdown.  Dropdown shows A,B,C,D,E,F. Upon rollover of B, a new 2nd dropdown populates with RED, BLUE, GREEN, PURPLE. Upon rolling over GREEN, a new dropdown populates with TALL, SHORT, MID. Upon that selection a 4th dropdown shows 34, 35, 36,37,38,39.

In a single cell selection the user now has defined 3 more data points tied to the initial selection without ever having to leave the first cell.  WAY FASTER for the user than choose and now go to another cell row and scroll to find the next, then again, then again. I have seen it used in other applications, but I just can't find a way to do it in Sheets. If the answer is out there please point me to it.

Comment: Welcome. What you are trying to achieve is generally described as "Multiple dependent drop down lists" and, based on your example, "Colour Size and Style" for the clothing industry. _I have seen it used in other applications, I just can't find a way to do it in sheets_. I wouldn't agree with that; there are many worked examples of multiple dependant drop downs for Google sheets but it is NOT a trivial undertaking and often requires scripting. Would you please summarise your research for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   I tried searching throughout this board and couldn't find any examples of solutions.  A few that listed a way to send to another sheet based upon the dropdown choice, but I didn't see any that referenced solutions to multiple dropdowns.    I am new to this exchange and maybe I don't know the ins and outs of finding what I am looking for.  I certainly do not mean to waste someones time.  I authored a software package long ago with multiple menus and it was a great solution.  It's for a training platform and I am trying to not reinvent the wheel.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree that pickings are slim on webapps, stackoverflow has much more; such as [Google Sheets - Dependent drop-down lists](Google Sheets - Dependent drop-down lists) or [How do you do dynamic / dependent drop downs in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21744547/1330560). Google "google sheets multiple dependent dropdown lists". Personally, I like the YouTube material by "Learn Google Spreadsheets"(ChcagoComputerClasses)-he has both script and non-script examples.

Comment: THANKS for responses.  I am trying to allow a series of roughly 9 menu categories that all are each dependent on the prior selection.  Rather than have the user menu over and then select, repeat, repeat, repeat, repeat etc....  I am trying to have in a single rollover state have the menu update and populate on the fly as you hover and slide right on each line.  For example - when you rollover TYPE A, your don't let up, a new menu appears right of it and shows you Color Options, Then Style etc.  Much faster and all in one cell dropdown.  Maybe that's what was explained.  I REALLY APPRECIATE IT!

Comment: _Maybe that's what was explained_ No, I described a dependant dropdown where nine menu options would require nine physical dropdowns. The mistake is mine; I can picture the UI for a single dropdown method but Google doesn't not support this natively. You might consider using the [API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) which would allow you to code in languages other than Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for multiple dropdowns of Type, Colour, Style and Size. You didn't say that the specific choices in each dropdown were dependant on those of the proceeding selection. Nor did you describe how the selections were to be used.

A simple, non-dependant version of this can be done by using Data Validation.
In the following example, Data Validation (Data, Data Validation, List from a Range) has been used.

- Cell A2 (Type): the validation range is "F2:F"
- Cell B2 (Colour): the validation range is "G2:G"
- Cell C2 (Style): the validation range is "H2:H"
- Cell D2 (Size): the validation range is "I2:I"

In each case, by leaving the range open-ended, it will ensure that you can add more Types/Colours/Styles/Sizes" and they will automatically appear in the respective lists

---

**Example**
[image: Data Validation screenshot]